# How to make the View to cover the whole screen?

Tags: android

I have a View which should cover the whole screen. But the problem is that it doesn't cover ToolBar. I tried simply View, I also tried `ImageView` with `setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)`. I can't figure out how to do it.

I need it to make my activity look inactive. Like on this screenshot:
[image]

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

  <View
    android:id="@+id/transparent_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="20"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:visibility="gone">
  </View>

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="Your Wi-Fi is online">

    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_pause"
      android:layout_width="90dp"
      android:layout_height="36dp"
      android:layout_margin="17dp"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:text="@string/pause"
      android:textColor="@color/midPurple"
      android:textSize="14sp" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    style="@style/AppTabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you explain more show your layout code and also if possible share image or screen shot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i'm correct understand you, you want to have full screen view?
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html